# How can I catch a specific column being out of range in Rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Say I have an integer column `sample_column` on a Rails model called `SampleModel`. I'm getting data from an external source, and I'm creating many new `SampleModel` rows using the `create!` method, and passing in all of the columns as part of the Hash argument of `create!`. Sometimes, the `sample_column` is too big (out of range), and MySQL throws an error, but it prevents the entire row from being saved. What I want to do instead is to just not write that `sample_column` to the DB so that it can save gracefully.

Is there any way to do this? Keep in mind that I don't know which column specifically will be out of range ahead of time since the data is unpredictable. So I want to catch everything and just ignore the column if it can't be written.

Comment: What type of error is exactly thrown? Does the error message contain the field name? You could catch the error and parse the message, then set the field to nil and try again...

Comment: Alternatively you could just change the column type to bigint so that no error is thrown

Comment: It was an out of range error, I actually want to anticipate any type of error, and just not write to the column if the error happens.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest changing the column type to bigint if size is the problem causing the model to break and if you are sure that this particular column is the only thing that causes it to break then i suggest you use rescue

```
begin
  SomeModel.create!(...., sample_column: hash[:sample_column])
rescue
  Somemodel.create!(....)
end
```

Comment: But is there a way to know in this case which column caused the error without having to parse the error message? Then I can call `create!` in the `rescue` block and not write the troublesome column.